# Why is it recommended to use concat then uglify when the latter can do both?

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I keep seeing the recommendation for making JS files ready for production to be concat then uglify.

For example [here](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#transformation-flow), in on of Yeoman's grunt tasks.

> By default the flow is: concat -> uglifyjs.

Considering UglifyJS can do both concatenation and minification, why would you ever need both at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: I used to use `concat`, but chose to use only `uglify`, which does all that's needed - as you pointed out. I guess some people use both to either compensate for the complexity of their projects or because they'd rather have `uglify` doing only what it does besides concatenation. `concat` also allows for separators, which `uglify` doesn't as far as I'm aware of.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Running a basic test to see if there is a performance difference between executing `concat` and then `uglify` vs. just `uglify`.

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "grunt-concat-vs-uglify",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A basic test to see if we can ditch concat and use only uglify for JS files.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^1.0.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Display the elapsed execution time of grunt tasks
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    // Load all grunt-* packages from package.json
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        paths: {
            src: {
                js: 'src/**/*.js'
            },
            dest: {
                js: 'dist/main.js',
                jsMin: 'dist/main.min.js'
            }
        },
        concat: {
            js: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';'
                },
                src: '<%= paths.src.js %>',
                dest: '<%= paths.dest.js %>'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                compress: true,
                mangle: true,
                sourceMap: true
            },
            target: {
                src: '<%= paths.src.js %>',
                dest: '<%= paths.dest.jsMin %>'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'concat vs. uglify', function (concat) {
        // grunt default:true
        if (concat) {
            // Update the uglify dest to be the result of concat
            var dest = grunt.config('concat.js.dest');
            grunt.config('uglify.target.src', dest);

            grunt.task.run('concat');
        }

        // grunt default
        grunt.task.run('uglify');
    });
};
```

In `src`, I've put a bunch of JS files, including the uncompressed source of jQuery, copied several times, spread around into subfolders. Much more than what a normal site/app usually has.

Turns out the time it takes to concat and compress all of these files is essentially the same in both scenarios.
**Except** when using the `sourceMap: true` option on `concat` as well (see below).

On my computer:

```
grunt default      : 6.2s (just uglify)
grunt default:true : 6s   (concat and uglify)
```

It's worth noting that the resulting `main.min.js` is the same in both cases.
Also, `uglify` automatically takes care of using the proper separator when combining the files.

The only case where it does matter is when adding `sourceMap: true` to the `concat` `options`.
This creates a `main.js.map` file next to `main.js`, and results in:

```
grunt default      : 6.2s (just uglify)
grunt default:true : 13s  (concat and uglify)
```

But if the production site loads only the `min` version, this option is useless.

I did found a major **disadvantage** with using `concat` before `uglify`.
When an error occurs in one of the JS files, the `sourcemap` will link to the concatenated `main.js` file and not the original file. Whereas when `uglify` does the whole work, it **will** link to the original file.

**Update:**
We can add 2 more options to `uglify` that will link the `uglify` sourcemap to `concat` sourcemap, thus handling the "disadvantage" I mentioned above.

```js
    uglify: {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            mangle: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapIncludeSources: true,
            sourceMapIn: '<%= paths.dest.js %>.map',
        },
        target: {
            src: '<%= paths.src.js %>',
            dest: '<%= paths.dest.jsMin %>'
        }
    }
```

But it seems highly unnecessary.

#### Conclusion

I think it's safe to conclude that we can ditch `concat` for JS files if we're using `uglify`, and use it for other purposes, when needed.

Comment: Nice effort at showing performance advantage! I'd just like to point out that my answer was meant to explain why some people still choose the [transformation flow](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#transformation-flow) (aka. `concat -> uglify`) workflow to `javascript` compilation. This workflow choice has little to do with performance - afaik - and I personally think it only makes sense in very complex projects.

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée Thanks! What would be the benefit of using `concat` before `uglify` in a very complex project? Perhaps the `process` option in concat?

Comment: There's another case you didn't consider: using concat but not uglify. You'd probably only use this when in development mode. My anecdotal tests show this to be on the order of 100x faster (example: 40ms vs 4s) which could be a huge benefit while you're working on your project.

Comment: @davethegr8 The OP asked specifically about the combination of `concat` with `uglify`. You're right if you only need to concat files and not compress them, you'd obviously use only `concat`, but that's not the discussed use case. And it's also better to develop on the end result any way. Less friction between dev and production.

Answer (score 29):

In the example you mention, which I'm quoting below, the files are first concatenated with `concat` and then uglified/minified by `uglify`:

```
{
  concat: {
    '.tmp/concat/js/app.js': [
      'app/js/app.js',
      'app/js/controllers/thing-controller.js',
      'app/js/models/thing-model.js',
      'app/js/views/thing-view.js'
    ]
  },
  uglifyjs: {
    'dist/js/app.js': ['.tmp/concat/js/app.js']
  }
}
```

The same could be achieved with:

```
{
  uglifyjs: {
    'dist/js/app.js': [
      'app/js/app.js',
      'app/js/controllers/thing-controller.js',
      'app/js/models/thing-model.js',
      'app/js/views/thing-view.js'
    ]
  }
}
```

Typically, the task `clean` would then run after tasks that write to a temporary folder (in this example `concat`) and delete whatever content is in that folder. Some people also like to run `clean` before tasks like `compass`, to delete things like randomly named image sprites (which are newly generated every time the task runs). This would keep wheels turning even for the most paranoid.

This is all a matter of preference and workflow, as is with when to run `jshint`. Some people like to run it before the compilation, others prefer to run it on compiled files.

Complex projects with an incredible amount of `JavaScript` files - or with a increasingly broad number of peers & contributors, might choose to concatenate files outside `uglify` just to keep things more readable and maintainable. I think this was the reasoning behind `Yeoman`'s choice of *transformation flow*.

`uglify` can be notoriously slow depending of the project's configuration, so there might be some small gain in concatenating it with `concat` first - but that would have to be confirmed.

`concat` also supports separators, which `uglify` doesn't as far as `README.md` files are concerned.

```
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';',
  }
}
```