# Concat and uglify in grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using grunt and was wondering what the best practice was regarding concat and uglify?

Which should I use first?

Should I concat the file and then uglify or uglify the file then concat?

Comment: First uglify then concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. Running uglify after concat will remove any introduced line breaks, but the size of the resulting file should be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to combine and compress JS files, `uglify` can do that by itself.

You should consider the performance implications of running `concat` before `uglify` when the `sourcemap` option is enabled.

See my detailed test case in this similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27452514/2048613