# Uglify directly or concat and uglify

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I am using grunt to build my JS project. I see that the uglify plugin for grunt is capable of merging multiple JS files into a single file and uglify them. Given this feature, I am wondering if there is a need to use concat plugin at all. Can I directly use uglify. Is there something that i am missing.

Most tutorials seem to suggest that I must first use concat then uglify.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27452514/2620998

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a separate concat tool. See [the docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) (under "Usage examples - Basic compression"). You just specify the files you want uglified, and it will concatenate them for you.